# How to push to or query local my local .NET nuget repository

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have a C# project that makes a lib. I build it just fine with `dotnet build`. I'd love to publish the dll to ~/.nuget/packages (I am on a Mac, using Rider). Is there a nuget command to query the local repository?

In terms of publishing, I have `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` added to the csproj file of the lib. Also `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>`, yet nothing is put into `~/.nuget/packages` if I do `dotnet pack`.

Comment: See [Create a NuGet package using the dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) and [Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

Answer (score 1):

```
dotnet build
dotnet pack
nuget add path/to/<yourProjeName>.nupkg -source ~/.nuget/packages
```

For Mac, `brew install nuget` is how you add a version of Nuget to your system. At least one that is different to the nuget built into the dotnet command that has a different syntax.

Then use `ls`, `find`, `ag` an wotnot for `~/.nuget` file location

Answer (score 1):

To publish NuGet package to your local repository you can either add the following property.

```
<PackageOutputPath>PATH_TO_YOUR_LOCAL_REPO</PackageOutputPath>
```

**NOTE:** Don't add the property to a csproj file, better adding it to Directory.Build.props and have it in .gitignore so you don't accidentally apply these changes to your CI build if there's any.

another way of doing it is by using dotnet cli pack via o option

```
dotnet pack -o PATH_TO_YOUR_LOCAL_REPO
```

Comment: Thx @Ibrahim, And the universal path for local is ~/.nuget/packages or ~/.nuget ?

Comment: @paul_h For windows, it's %userprofile%\.nuget\packages and for linux/mac it's ~/.nuget/packages. But I advise you against publishing the packages in this folder because it's where nuget keeps the cached installed packages and it stores the packages in some special folder structure along with meta-data. Choose a different folder for your local repo something like %userprofile%/my-nuget-repo.